# Why mockito will trigger the verify twice?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I notice this problem during the following test:

```
verify(mockedObject).functionCall(argThat(inputStream -> {
    final String content = ... // read the inputStream
    assertEquals(expectedContent, content);
    return true;
}));
```

It will actually fail although the `assertEquals` assertion is true. I debug the test, find that the lambda function is reached twice, and at the second time, the cursor of the stream is at the end of the stream. That's why it fails.

So I have to reset the stream first:

```
verify(mockedObject).functionCall(argThat(inputStream -> {
    inputStream.reset();
    final String content = ... // read the inputStream
    assertEquals(expectedContent, content);
    return true;
}));
```

The question is, why the lambda is triggered twice? Is this by design? Does it have a document?

Mockito version: 2.22

Junit version: 5.6.0

Java version: 1.8

### Update

The method is called exactly once, and the inputs of two lambda calls are exactly the same input. Actually, they are the same object. The only thing I have to do is to reset the stream, as it has been exhausted by the first lambda call.

Comment: Totally random guess: how many methods of `mockedObject` are you invoking? Is it possible that the second time a method is invoked is one with no arguments?

Comment: @Pelocho Just once, otherwise the whole verify would fail right? `verify(mockedObject)` is an alias of `verify(mockedObject, times(1))`.

Comment: @Sraw the `times(1)` takes into accound the matching that you perform in `argThat`. If it's called twice with different inputs and only one them matches, the verify succeeds.

Comment: @ttzn Thanks, there are two things I can ensure. First, the method is called only once. Second, the lambda is triggered twice by the same input, when I reach the second lambda call, the `inputStream` is exactly the same as the first one. I will update this information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's "by design", rather that it's what the current implementation does. The Mockito `Times` class which performs your assertions has the following method (I'm on a pretty recent version so YMMV):

```
public void verify(VerificationData data) {
    List<Invocation> invocations = data.getAllInvocations();
    MatchableInvocation wanted = data.getTarget();

    if (wantedCount > 0) {
        checkMissingInvocation(data.getAllInvocations(), data.getTarget());
    }
    checkNumberOfInvocations(invocations, wanted, wantedCount);
}
```

Both `checkMissingInvocation` and `checkNumberOfInvocations` perform independent filtering on the list of all invocations to retain the relevant ones, so any matcher you declare ends up being executed twice for each invocation. It's actually exactly the same call:

```
List<Invocation> actualInvocations = findInvocations(invocations, wanted);
```

Maybe the filtered list could be cached, but the point is that unless otherwise specified in the documentation, you cannot assume that the function you supply will be executed only once. Also, predicate functions are generally expected to be free of side-effects.

Comment: It makes sense that the matcher should be idempotent. Thanks for diving into the source code, following your path I find the same source code which provides the behavior. Hum, I think this should be documented anyway.